# Input in one line of code is acting as input of second line of code,how do i separate these two lines of code?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program where a user enters values of variable a and variable b
and resulting output should be in this format.

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
```

How do i make sure that my variables don't interfere with each other?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int a,b;
cin>>a>>b;
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
cout<<a<<endl;
cout<<b;
}
```

Comment: `const int sum = a + b; const int diff = a - b;`?

Comment: `std::tie(a, b) = std::tuple(a + b, a - b);` if really you don't want to introduce new variable names...

Comment: Use more variables.

Answer (score 3):

Just introduce extra variables:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    const int sum = a + b;
    const int diff = a - b;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << diff;
}
```

or use computation when needed:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
    std::cout << a - b;
}
```

Else you have to use convoluted way which would probably be less readable.

Answer (score 1):

For starters if you are going just to output values of the expressions `a + b` and `a - b` then it is enough to write one statement as for example

```
std::cout << "a + b = " << a + b << ", a - b = " << a - b << '\n';
```

If you indeed need to assign new values to the variables `a` and `b` then you can use for example a temporary intermediate variable.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    int tmp = a + b;
    b  = a - b;
    a = tmp;
    
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter two values `10` and `5` then the output will be

```
a = 15, b = 5
```

If you want to know something new about C++ then you can use the standard function [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) declared in the header `<utility>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    b = std::exchange( a, a + b ) - b;
    
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again if to enter the same values as above then the output will be the same

```
a = 15, b = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have:

```
a = a + b
b = a - b
```

in the end and not to use any other variable you can also do it like:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int a,b;
cin>>a>>b;
a = a + b;
b = a - ( 2 * b);
cout<<a<<endl;
cout<<b;
}
```

but please note that it is not a good practice to use `using namespace std;` . instead do it like:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{

int a,b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
a = a + b;
b = a - ( 2 * b);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```